# spring-cloud-aws Spring creates message header attribute not supported by SQS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-sqs

I'm using Spring Cloud AWS messaging to send/receive messages using SQS.

My code looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(MessagingConfig.class)
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}


@Configuration
public class MessagingConfig {

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQS amazonSqs, ResourceIdResolver resourceIdResolver) {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqs, resourceIdResolver);
    }

}
```

The sender code is like this (wired via a controller):

```
@Component
public class Sender {

    @Autowired
    private QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;

    public void send(MyMessage message) {
        queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("testQueue", message);
    }
}
```

I have an `application.yaml` file that defines the AWS parameters that seem to be correctly loaded. So, when I run this application, I get the following warning/error:

```
Message header with name 'id' and type 'java.util.UUID' cannot be sent as message attribute because it is not supported by SQS.
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong here, or is there an issue with the way Spring creates messages for SQS?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be only a warning and does not affect the sending and/or receiving of the message. When I tested this against a real SQS queue, I could both send and receive messages.

However, when using elasticMQ on my local box as a replacement for the real SQS, it was failing to process the message. It looks like an issue with that tool rather than Spring.

Answer (score 0):

How to answer the question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483292/spring-cloud-aws-invalid-header-posting-sns-notification)

The problem occurs because the constructor called MessageHeaders class

MessageHeaders class

```
MessageHeaders(Map<String, Object> headers) { } on line 39
```

And to not send the id header you need to call the constructor 
MessageHeaders class

```
MessageHeaders(Map<String, Object> headers, UUID id, Long timestamp){} on line 43
```

because this constructor has the condition does not create the id header automatically

to stop sending the header id you need to override the MessageHeader and NotificationMessagingTemplate classes

class MessageHeaders

```
public class MessageHeadersCustom extends MessageHeaders {
    public MessageHeadersCustom() {
        super(new HashMap<String, Object>(), ID_VALUE_NONE, null);
    }
}
```

class NotificationMessagingTemplate

```
public class NotificationMessagingTemplateCustom extends NotificationMessagingTemplate {

    public NotificationMessagingTemplateCustom(AmazonSNS amazonSns) {
        super(amazonSns);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendNotification(Object message, String subject) {

        MessageHeaders headersCustom = new MessageHeadersCustom();
        headersCustom.put(TopicMessageChannel.NOTIFICATION_SUBJECT_HEADER, subject);

        this.convertAndSend(getRequiredDefaultDestination(), message, headersCustom);
    }
}
```

And finally, your class that will make the call need to use your implementation

```
package com.stackoverflow.sample.web;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.NotificationMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/whatever")
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationMessagingTemplateCustom template;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String handleGet() {
            this.template.sendNotification("message", "subject");
            return "yay";
        }
    }
}
```