# Spring Cloud AWS - Invalid Header posting SNS notification

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-sns

I'm trying to use `org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.NotificationMessagingTemplate` (from Spring Cloud AWS) to post notifications to a SNS Topic.

Every time a notification is posted a warning message is generated:

WARN [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.TopicMessageChannel] Message header with name 'id' and type 'java.util.UUID' cannot be sent as message attribute because it is not supported by SNS.

The issue seems to be that `org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders` generates automagically an id header, of type java.util.UUID, which is not something that spring cloud knows how to handle.

Is there a way to avoid that automatic header generation (I can live without an UUID here) or avoid the warning, besides just suppressing the log?

Something similar is also affecting SQS:

Related Question: 
[spring-cloud-aws Spring creates message header attribute not supported by SQS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814139/spring-cloud-aws-spring-creates-message-header-attribute-not-supported-by-sqs)
[Related Bug: Warning "'java.util.UUID' cannot be sent as message attribute ..." on any request sent to SQS channel](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/86)

My Controller looks something like this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.sample.web;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.NotificationMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/whatever")
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationMessagingTemplate template;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String handleGet() {
            this.template.sendNotification("message", "subject");
            return "yay";
        }
    }
}
```

My Spring configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
        xmlns:aws-messaging="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/spring-cloud-aws-messaging.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.stackoverflow.sample" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <aws-context:context-credentials>
        <aws-context:instance-profile-credentials/>
        <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="MyKey" secret-key="mySecret" />
    </aws-context:context-credentials>

    <aws-messaging:notification-messaging-template id="notificationMessagingTemplate" region="us-west-2" default-destination="myTopic" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because the constructor called MessageHeaders class

MessageHeaders class

```
MessageHeaders(Map<String, Object> headers) { } on line 39
```

And to not send the id header you need to call the constructor 
MessageHeaders class

```
MessageHeaders(Map<String, Object> headers, UUID id, Long timestamp){} on line 43
```

because this constructor has the condition does not create the id header automatically

to stop sending the header id you need to override the MessageHeader and NotificationMessagingTemplate classes

class MessageHeaders

```
public class MessageHeadersCustom extends MessageHeaders {
    public MessageHeadersCustom() {
        super(new HashMap<String, Object>(), ID_VALUE_NONE, null);
    }
}
```

class NotificationMessagingTemplate

```
public class NotificationMessagingTemplateCustom extends NotificationMessagingTemplate {

    public NotificationMessagingTemplateCustom(AmazonSNS amazonSns) {
        super(amazonSns);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendNotification(Object message, String subject) {

        MessageHeaders headersCustom = new MessageHeadersCustom();
        headersCustom.put(TopicMessageChannel.NOTIFICATION_SUBJECT_HEADER, subject);

        this.convertAndSend(getRequiredDefaultDestination(), message, headersCustom);
    }
}
```

And finally, your class that will make the call need to use your implementation

```
package com.stackoverflow.sample.web;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.NotificationMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/whatever")
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationMessagingTemplateCustom template;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String handleGet() {
            this.template.sendNotification("message", "subject");
            return "yay";
        }
    }
}
```